# Python. Incorrectly structured while loop?

Tags: python

I have a code that generates triangular numbers, calculates the divisors for each triangular number and prints out 3 columns where the first column is the input numbers, the second column is the triangular numbers and the third column is the divisors of each triangular number. I want this code to stop once a triangular number with number of divisors more or equal to 10 is found. I set that condition under the second "if" statement, however the "break" doesn't actually break the while loop and end up with en infinite loop. Is the placement of "break" wrong?

```
n=1
while True:
    for num in range(n,n+1):
        divisors = []
        triangle_number = num*(num+1)//2
        for divisor in range(1, triangle_number+1):
            if triangle_number%divisor == 0:
                divisors.append(divisor)
        if len(divisors) >= 10:
            print(num, end = '\t')
            print(triangle_number, end = '\t')
            print(len(divisors), "\t", ",".join(str(div )for div in divisors))
            break
        else:
            n+=1
```

Comment: break keyword is in for loop scope, declare bool variable in global scope and pass it to while and change the value in nested loop where you are breaking it

Comment: What basit is saying: `break` only breaks the innermost loop it's nested in. So it may break the inner `for` loop, but the outer `while` loop is still going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `flag` variable to control the outer loop. Look at this code and try it.

```
n=1
flag = True
while flag is True:
    for num in range(n,n+1):
        divisors = []
        triangle_number = num*(num+1)//2
        for divisor in range(1, triangle_number+1):
            if triangle_number%divisor == 0:
                divisors.append(divisor)
        if len(divisors) >= 10:
            print(num, end = '\t')
            print(triangle_number, end = '\t')
            print(len(divisors), "\t", ",".join(str(div )for div in divisors))
            flag = False
            break
        else:
            n+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the break only stops the for loop, not the while loop in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is:

```
n=1
while len(divisors) < 11:
    for num in range(n,n+1):
```

Answer (score 0):

Break stops the execution of the inner most loop in Python. In case of the nested loops and it has to be handled by the program.

For the code above the break makes the execution come out of the for loop and continues with the while loop execution.

Sample code to handle this scenario.

```
break_flag = False
while True:
   while True:
      if some_condition:
         break_flag = True
         break
   if break_flag:
      break
```